# Fix broken tensorflow-gpu installation

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, tensorflow

I have a broken installation of tensorflow and cannot find a way to correct it to start clean from the beginning. I am using the instructions [in the tensorflow website for Ubuntu 18.04 (CUDA 10)](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu).

Everything goes very well, the drivers install, the gpu samples compile and run correctly... Until the very last step, installing libnvinfer, where I get this error:

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>
> libnvinfer-dev : Depends: libnvinfer5 (= 5.0.2-1+cuda10.0) but 5.1.5-1+cuda10.1 is to be installed
>
> E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

It seems that *something* is pointing at cuda10.1 somewhere, because of a previous broken installation. My issue is that I already searched for, deleted, purged and uninstalled everything that I could think of. There should be no nvidia things in the computer now... Or yes, but I can't find it.

Any ideas on where or how to look for whatever I am missing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)